How do I properly compute a convolution kernel given the convolved and initial signal?
I'm trying to for solve for $ b $ in the equation $C = a*b$ where $C,a,b$ are 1D arrays of size $k$. $F(b)$ is also $= \frac{1}{|F(a)|}$. I have tried doing the following procedure in order to isolate b:
$F(C) = F(a*b) = F(a)F(b)$
$b = F^{-1}(\frac{F(C)}{F(a)})$
However, whenever I perform the the convolution $a*b$ I do not get back to C. Here is the implementation in code:
Fa = np.fft.fft(a)
normFa = Fa/np.abs(Fa)

FC = normFa
C = np.real(np.fft.ifft(normFa))

Fb = FC/Fa
b = np.real(np.fft.ifft(Fb))

Result = np.convolve(a,b, mode="same")

I made sure the imaginary parts in $C$ and $b$ were negligible.
Do you see where this deconvolution procedure could have gone wrong? Seeing there are different ways of applying a convolution, (seen by the different mode parameters in np.convolve()) which one is the one that matches the convolution theorem?
What is weird is that whenever I change the mode parameter to "full", the result is a $2k$-length signal with the first k samples being simply $a$ and the other $k$ samples being $a$ flipped down, almost like b had no effect on the first k points of the signal.
If I were to code a version of np.convolve() myself, how should the operation go if I want C to be as the same size as a and b? I'm having trouble bridging the gaps between the continuous and the discrete case.
Thanks again!
Edit: I Now realize that perhaps this could have something to do with the size of $b$. I do not necessarily need $b$ to be of length $k$.

Use some form of the Fourier Transform and division.

@robertbristow-johnson That's what I did. F(x) refers to a Fourier Transform.

Whenever you are dividing by some signal or its Transform, there is always the possibility of dividing by zero. That could be one issue. Another issue could be that all your arrays are the same size. But the result of a convolution has length equal to the sum of the lengths of the signals being convolved minus one. To better help you out we need more information. Perhaps the difference is not that big anyways...

@AhsanYousaf I will investigate the division my zero possibility. The resulting convolution is indeed of length k, and is very different from the one done with the division in Fourier space.

The reason it fails is that an inherent assumption in the discrete Fourier transform is that your signals are periodic (repeat themselves indefinitely). However, when you computed your convolution to check the result at the end, the convolve function is assuming that the signals are zero outside the range of your data, which does not satisfy the periodic signal assumption.
One solution is to satisfy circular convolution, which will make Result == C:
Result = scipy.signal.convolve(a,numpy.concatenate(b,b), mode="same")

Another solution is to use the scipy.signal.deconvolve function instead to determine b, which will make Result == C when an exact solution exists (for demonstration purposes, I have guaranteed this in the following):
C = scipy.signal.convolve(a,b)
b = scipy.signal.deconvolve(C,a)
Result = scipy.signal.convolve(a,b)

I cannot replicate your "weird observation" when the convolve function returns the full result, thus believe it to be an artefact of your a vector (I tested using a random vector for a).
Regarding coding your own version of convolve, the link between these discrete domain functions and the continuous domain result has two aspects. Firstly, the discrete case is a numerically integrated approximation of the continuous case using the rectangular rule, so one part lacking from these functions is multiplying by the discrete time interval if you want to match the scaling. Secondly, these functions only work with finite length signals, outside of which it is assumed the signals are zero, and so to provide an approximation for the full continuous convolution, your signals must satisfy this. The "mode" argument simply dictates which section of the convolution is returned, so if you want b to have the same size as a and C, you need to work out which section of the convolution that corresponds to, and then either use mode = full and isolate it yourself, or if one of the other modes already provides what you want to isolate, conveniently use that as a shortcut.
